# Sort an array of objects according to another array of objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have two objects. I want to sort first object's `QuickLinks` property according to second object's `QuickLinks`. It should be based on `QuickLinkContent.ConfigId`

```
NavigationMenuContent nmc1 = new NavigationMenuContent();
NavigationMenuContent nmc2 = new NavigationMenuContent();

public class NavigationMenuContent
    {
        public int LanguageID { get; set; }

        public QuickLinkContent[] QuickLinks { get; set; }
    }

public class QuickLinkContent
    {
        public Guid ConfigID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public Guid? ServiceProviderID { get; set; }

        public SchemeContentFile Document { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
nmc1.QuickLinks = nmc1.QuickLinks.OrderBy(q => nmc2.QuickLinks.ToList().IndexOf(q.ConfigID));
```

but getting error :

`Cannot convert from System.Guid to QuickLnkContent.`

Comment: You say you want to sort `nmc1` list, but you are trying to sort `QuickLinks` array. So what you are actually trying to sort?

Comment: I want to sort nmc1.QuickLinks according to nmc2.QuickLinks

Comment: What does that even mean? For example, if I said "I want to sort this Person[] according to FirstName alphabetical descending" - that makes sense.. but "I want to sort this Person[] according to that Person[]" - it's not a specification of anything

Comment: `nmc1` is a list. it doesn't have property `QuickLinks`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy sorry for confustion, I've updated the question

Comment: Types are always your friend in C#: what is the type of `q.ConfigID`? What is the type of `nmc2.QuickLinks`? How do you expect `IndexOf` to work?

Comment: What does "according to" mean? Be specific.

Comment: I meant QuickLinkContent.ConfigId

Comment: Do the `QuickLinkContent[] QuickLinks` arrays contain the same `Guid ConfigID`, just in a different order? What if there are missing items; do the missing elements get sorted to the end of the list?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, it contains same configId. There won't be missing items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create array of ordered config ids:

```
var orderedIds = nmc2.QuickLinks.Select(ql => ql.ConfigID).ToArray();
```

And then use it to order links

```
nmc1.QuickLinks = nmc1.QuickLinks
   .OrderBy(ql => Array.IndexOf(orderedIds, ql.ConfigID))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: O(n2) operation. The other solution will usually be faster

Comment: @Charlieface first of all it's premature optimization. You don't want to create dictionaries to sort an array of 5 items. And other solution will fail 1) when nmc1 has unique items, 2) when nmc2 has duplicates. So you (maybe) saved few ticks of cpu, but got more code to maintain and two problems to deal with

Answer (score 3):

I would use a dictionary to do this.

```
Dictionary<Guid, int> map =
    nmc2
        .QuickLinks
        .Select((x, n) => (x, n))
        .ToDictionary(z => z.x.ConfigID, z => z.n);

nmc1.QuickLinks =
    nmc1
        .QuickLinks
        .OrderBy(x => map[x.ConfigID])
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the faster method usually

Answer (score 1):

Using an array extension method, you can solve this generally:

```
public static int IndexOfBy<T, TKey>(this T[] a, TKey target, Func<T,TKey> keyFn, EqualityComparer<TKey> cmp = null) {
    cmp = cmp ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < a.Length; ++j1) {
        if (cmp.Equals(keyFn(a[j1]), target))
            return j1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

With the extension method available, you can use `OrderBy`:

```
nmc1.QuickLinks = nmc2.QuickLinks.OrderBy(q => nmc2.QuickLinks.IndexOfBy(q.ConfigID, q2 => q2.ConfigID)).ToArray();
```